# HTML title showing as plaintext and not in title

Tags: html, css, web, text, title

My super-simplified code still does not display the necessary in the title in the browser. This occurs in both Firefox and Chrome and the title{display:none;}-css-solution did not make a difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <tile>Pong</tile>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo it has to be `<title>` , not `<tile>`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Pong</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you! What a terrible mistake to make!

Comment: @BernardvanTonder Can you make this answer the accepted answer. :)